# Force Ubuntu to only download updates form canonical.com mirrors

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, repository, official-repositories

How do I force a Ubuntu machine to only download updates from official canonical.com mirrors? Right now it sometimes downloads from non canonical mirrors, which get flagged in our network monitoring software.

(Note: We don't have any third party repositories on this machine)

Answer (score 2):

In the software sources (synaptic packages manager -> settings -> repositories), you can manage your mirrors

Answer (score 2):

you can also edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file which contains all the repositories details.

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then update once:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

when you open the sources.list file, you will find different keywords after the name of the repositories.

1. "main restricted" -> part of canonical
2. "universe" -> N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
3. "multiverse" -> N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu  team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in  multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
4. **"partner" -> other than canonical**

Remove the following if present. These are third party repositories:

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main

deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ quantal main

Comment: sources.list has the following repositories:
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ . However the machine still downloads from non-canonical servers. Any ideas?

Comment: @SaqibAli please refer to updated answer